# Delete folders and files in C:\Windows\servicing\LCU and C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download folders

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete all files and folders in these 2 folders using these powershell commands:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\servicing\LCU -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

But I keep getting errors like "access denied" or "cannot find path" etc, does anyone have a script or command that I could run on remote servers to clean up these folders?

Thanks

Comment: Is powershell running as administrator? btw, if you're `Remove-Item -Recurse` then don't use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`...

Comment: Yes running powershell as admin, snip of the error:

`
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.2803.1.3\
amd64_0a43ebd87f4b55cd868cb7e664d03930_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1971_none_4a4d3a6c73abc47d.manifest: Access to the
path is denied.`

Comment: You may need to set Full Control or Ownership on the folders

Answer (score 1):

Take ownership of directories and subdirectories (/R for recursive)
Grants ownership of these directories as account running the script

- takeown /R /F C:\Windows\servicing\LCU*
- takeown /R /F C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download*

Then use your code

- Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\servicing\LCU -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
  -Recurse
- Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download -Recurse |
  Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

Comment: This works, well it deletes more files/folders but it's still not taking ownership of the sub folders for some reason then when I run the script it still comes up with access denied errors on some of the folders/files